# How to get Object idle time using Spring boot Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I am trying to implement session management, where we store jwt token to redis. Now  I want remove the key if the object idle time is more than 8 hours. Pls help

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use EXPIRE each time you access the key? It's the idiomatic way to do this. https://redis.io/commands/expire#refreshing-expires You'd anyway be doing two Redis commands for both getting OBJECT IDLETIME and then DEL or using GET and then EXPIRE.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason that comes to my mind for using `IDLETIME` instead of using the much simpler pattern of issuing a `GET` followed by an `EXPIRE` apart from very trivial memory requirements for key expiry.

### Recommended Way: `GET` and `EXPIRE`

1. `GET` the key you want.
2. Issue an `EXPIRE <key> 28800`.

### Way using `OBJECT IDLETIME`, `DEL` and some application logic:

1. `GET` the key you want.
2. Call `OBJECT IDLETIME <key>`.
3. Check in your application code if the idletime > 8h.
4. If condition 3 is met, then issue a `DEL` command.

The second way is more cumbersome and introduces network latency since you need three round trips to your redis server while the first solution just does it in one round trip if you use a pipeline or two round trips without any app server time at worst.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did using Jedis. I am fetching 1000 records at a time. You can add a loop to fetch all records in a batch.

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("addURLHere");
ScanParams scanParams = new ScanParams().count(1000);

ScanResult<String> scanResult = jedis.scan(ScanParams.SCAN_POINTER_START, scanParams);
List<String> result = scanResult.getResult();
result.stream().forEach((key) -> {
                if (jedis.objectIdletime(key) > 8 * 60 * 60) { // more than 5 days
                    //your functionality here
                }
            });`
```